# AngularJS Routing not working even on webserver

Tags: angularjs, django

Hey I'm working on a web development tutorial involving django and angular and I ran into an issue where my angularJS routing is not working even when running on local server...so what happens is that the index.html loads with the background image and the navbar but the rest of the html is not there.

Here's my code:

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html ng-app="thinkster">
     <head>
      <title>HRLite Home</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <base href="/" />

      <!-- Fonts -->
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Raleway:500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

      <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <!-- Scripts -->
      {% include 'javascripts.html' %}
      {% include 'stylesheets.html' %}
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular-route.min.js"></script>
      <script src="static/javascripts/thinkster.routes.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
      {% include 'navbar.html' %}
      <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

thinkster.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('thinkster', [
        'thinkster.config'
        'thinkster.routes',
        'thinkster.authentication'
    ]);

angular
    .module('thinkster.config, []');

angular
    .module('thinkster.routes', ['ngRoute']);

angular
    .module('thinkster')
    .run(run);

run.$inject = ['$http'];

/**
* @name run
* @desc Update xsrf $http headers to align with Django's defaults
*/
function run($http) {
    $http.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    $http.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
}
})();
```

thinkster.routes.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('thinkster.routes')
    .config(config);

config.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

/**
 * @name config
 * @desc Define valid application routes
 */
function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl "static/templates/authentication/home.html"
    }).when('/register', {
        controller: 'RegisterController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        templateUrl: '/templates/authentication/register.html'
    }).when('/login', {
        controller: 'LoginController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        templateUrl: '/templates/authentication/login.html'
    }).otherwise('/'();
}})();
```

I'm fairly new to angular so it's probably a stupid mistake i've made! If anyone can help out it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't see a `<script>` tag for `thinkster.js`. Is your Angular app even loading?

Comment: @Lex thanks for the response, but yeah it's in the javascripts.html file that is included in the header. But even when I add the thinkster.js script last nothing changes!

Comment: What happens if you change angular.js and angular-route.js to be the same version? I have seen some very inconsistent and problematic behavior when using different versions of the core Angular libraries.

Comment: Please look at browser's developers console, have it loaded your template "static/templates/authentication/home.html" for main page?

Comment: @atn yeah thanks it ended up being a stupid mistake in my syntax!